# php echo wordpress user meta data

Tags: php, wordpress

On my site when a user is registering there is an option to pick from an additional option that pears their account up with a non-profit. Once the user has registered and viewing specific pages of the site I want the site to be tailored to them using php that grabs their meta info. For this I will echo a button that tailors the front-end based on what meta value they have selected when registering.

If they have no meta key, then nothing is shown.

Here is my code attempt, but does not work!

```
    <?php global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo(); //wordpress global variable to fetch logged in user info
$userID = $current_user->ID; //logged in user's ID
$havemeta1 = get_user_meta($userID,'nch',true); //stores the value of logged in user's meta data for 'National Coalition for the homeless'
$havemeta2 = get_user_meta($userID,'rotary-international',true); //stores the value of logged in user's meta data for 'Rotary International'
$havemeta3 = get_user_meta($userID,'khan-academy',true); //stores the value of logged in user's meta data for 'Khan Academy'
$havemeta4 = get_user_meta($userID,'wwf',true); //stores the value of logged in user's meta data for 'World Wildlife Fund (WWF)'
$havemeta5 = get_user_meta($userID,'bcrf',true); //stores the value of logged in user's meta data for 'The Breast Cancer Research Foundation'
?>

<!--add if statement to figure out what button to show to logged in user-->

<?php if ($havemeta1) { ?>
   <div <p>nch</p> class="Button1"></div>
<?php } elseif ($havemeta2) { ?>
   <div <p>rotary-international</p>class="Button2"></div>
<?php } elseif ($havemeta3) { ?>
   <div <p>khan-academy</p>class="Button3"></div>
<?php } elseif ($havemeta4) { ?>
   <div <p>wwf</p>class="Button4"></div>
<?php } elseif ($havemeta5) { ?>
   <div <p>bcrf</p>class="Button5"></div>
<?php } else { ?>
   <div><p>None - No Matching Affiliation</p></div>
<?php }?>
```

-----------------------New Code----------------------

This allows me to see what the affiliation variable is pulling for the user
The result is this: 'User Affiliation: khan-academy'

```
<?php global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

      echo 'User Affiliation: ' . $current_user->affiliation . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you pass the meta into a session var, ie $_SESSION['havemeta5'];

Answer (score 0):

`get_user_meta` is set up wrong. Try this:

```
$havemeta1 = get_user_meta( $userID, 'nch', true );
```

...and so on. You need to pass the `$userID` as the first parameter of `get_user_meta()` - not `$affiliation`.

**update**

If your user meta is 'affiliation' (which allows you to call $current_user->affiliation), you can do something like this:

```
<?php
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$userID = $current_user->ID;
$affiliation = get_user_meta( $userID, 'affiliation', false );
$affiliation = $affiliation[0];
if( 'nch' == $affiliation ){
  print '<div class="Button1"><p>nch</p></div>';
} elseif( 'rotary-international' == $affiliation ){
  print '<div class="Button2"><p>Rotary International</p></div>';
} elseif( 'khan-academy' == $affiliation ){
  print '<div class="Button3"><p>Khan Academy</p></div>';
} elseif( 'wwf' == $affiliation ){
  print '<div class="Button4"><p>wwf</p></div>';
} elseif( 'bcrf' == $affiliation ){
  print '<div class="Button5"><p>bcrf</p></div>';
} else {
  print '<div><p>None - no matching affiliation</p></div>';
  print '<div>User ID: '.$userID.', Affiliation: '.$affiliation.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: ok I have replaced the $affiliation with $userID but am still not getting any results..

Comment: Did you check the database to see if the user meta is being set and actually exists?

Comment: Yes, I know it works because I have a php script the echos what the variable is. I added it above. I know the information is being successfully pulled out of the database. I am getting khan-academy

Comment: Try: $affiliation = get_user_meta( $userID, 'affiliation', true ); and then use the $affiliation variable in your if statement.

Comment: Doesn't seem to of changed anything. Also how will it be able to match up the variables if I don't switch up the variable name?

Comment: Man still a no go. Wonder where it is going wrong.
'wwf' == $affiliation   Does that mean it looks to see what meta that variable is and if it equals? I feel like this should work perfectly

Comment: What do you get when you enter this code: $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $userID ); print_r( $all_meta_for_user );

Comment: nothing.. What should I be getting a long list a meta data?

Comment: Yep - all meta data for that user. Are you sure you're getting the $userID? can you print $userID and get a number back?

Comment: if I write it like this: echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
I get 'User ID: 1' displayed. The "\n"; might have something to do with it. I'm not sure I found that code online

Comment: After that line, try $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID ); print_r( $all_meta_for_user ); and let me know what comes out

Comment: Hey Joe, ok looks like it works It sent me a whole bunch of lines. Far to much to post here haha anything I should look for?

Comment: You should see something like Array( [first_name] => Array( [0] => something ), ..., [affiliation] => Array( [0] => something )... ) Do you see the affiliation in the array?

Comment: Yes. [affiliation] => Array ( [0] => khan-academy )

Comment: See the updated code again. The user meta is there. I just gave you the full code to try (under update). If you end up with None - no matching affiliation, let me know what prints after it for user ID and affiliation.

Comment: With that new code above it does not print anything.. If I use global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo(); it does work but shows 'none'

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is with the meta saving multiple versions of the user meta which would then spit back an array. In this case, using 'true' won't work for a single key. Instead, try the updated code.

Comment: Hey Joe, wow I think we got it lol the current update works perfectly (just need to put in the ?>)

Thanks a lot. I wonder what would fix the original code

Comment: I don't know how your meta is being created, but if you're 1) using add_user_meta more than once for the user per affiliation (or if you did previously) or 2) storing the value as an array or 3) using the fourth parameter of update_user_meta (the previous value parameter), that's the problem. You could try to delete_user_meta( $userID, 'affiliation' ) to get rid of them all for that user, and then reset it with update_user_meta( $userID, 'affiliation', whatever_value ); which will then create the one affiliation meta for that user which can be accessed as a string with the get_user_meta & true

Comment: Looks like you gave me a bit of homework with that last post haha thanks. I have another question. I am trying to add this in the widgets area on WP and it seems that Button3 class is not pulling css .Button3 currently. Should I start this convo as a new topic?

Comment: Yes - mark this as resolved/answered and then start a new one because we'll need to see your CSS.